# EWS AutoDiscoverUrl Times Out

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I have been trying to execute the example given in the below MSDN link.

[Using Autodiscover with Exchange Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/gg591268%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)

When I pass my valid email id & the password, the application simply times out. It doesnt throw any other exception.

Please share your thoughts as to how I can find out the Service URL?

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Is exchange behind any firewall?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is behind the firewall. In my opinion, it should be behind the firewall only according to the Security Policies implemented by the organization. How does it impact?

Comment: If there's a firewall blocking that port you will get a timeout with no error from the web server.